# Error accessing Synapse lake database from Azure data factory - Cannot find the CREDENTIAL

Tags: azure, azure-synapse-analytics

We are trying to access a Azure Synapse lake database from Azure data factory pipeline.But when ADF runs a query on the lake database(dataverse) we get the below error.

Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Cannot find the CREDENTIAL 'https:/xxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/dataverse-xxxxx/deltalake/xxxx', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.',

This is using a linked service with sql authentication

We have granted all possible levels of access to ADF on the synapse analytics as well as the adls storage account.

This works with a synapse pipeline in the synapse environment but not from the ADF.